# Programmatically deselecting a row in JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, jcheckbox, listselectionlistener

I want to programmatically deselect a row in JTable. Basically I have  cehckbix in my jtable and my row needs to be selected or highlited when I click on checkbox. CLicking in any other column should not highlight the row.

I tries table.removeRowSelectionInterval(row,row) on clicking in cell other than checkbox it did not work.

I tried ListSelectionModelk.clearSelection() and then adding RowSelectionInterval() for rows as needed, it works but it interfere with some other functionality.

So I can't use this.

Comment: Why not implements your own cell renderer which deals with the background color to hilight some rows ?

Comment: _needs to be selected or highlited_ these are separate concepts, which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nizil commented that you can write your own [Cell Renderer](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html) or [Cell Renderer](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node170.html)

You also need to look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to use CheckBoxes](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/post1.0/ui/checkbox.html)